# Cannot upgrade to latest BIOS for Lenovo Thinkpad P43s

Tags: bios, thinkpad

In windows 10 under msinfo I can see that I have this version of BIOS installed:

```
BIOS Version/Date   LENOVO N2IET88W (1.66 ), 22/04/2020
```

I have downloaded the latest version (1.67) of the BIOS driver for my Lenovo P43s laptop here:

https://support.lenovo.com/dk/en/downloads/ds539061

```
Version 1.67/1.1203 Jul 2020
```

But when I install it from windows 10 I get:

[image]

Why does it think I have the latest installed when I clearly have not and how do I get 1.67 installed?

**UPDATE:**
Looks like the download for **n2iuj22w.exe** is actually downloading https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles/n2iuj11w.exe

[image]

But if I manually update that download link to:

https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles/n2iuj22w.exe

I get the correct/latest version

Comment: If I download file **n2iuj22w.exe** from the page you linked and execute WINUPTP64.EXE after I extracted the archive, the Flash Update Utility starts and it looks like yours, except mine says **Version 34.21** and (C) COPYRIGHT LENOVO 2005,**2020**.

Comment: Ok, now that you're downloading a different file, does it work?

Comment: If OP never responds, we know he has updated the BIOS and that failed ;-D